# With Xamarin for Android is Mono runtime installed more than once?

Tags: android, xamarin, mono

AFAIK desktop apps developed with any .NET language (C#, VB.NET, F#, etc.) 
didn't include .NET runtime and all apps ran over the same .NET framework.

For Android this is not true. Every app include the Mono framework inside the APK.

So, Xamarin-generated APKs are HUGE !

As you can see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/) the 6K HelloWord App grows up to 15.8M with the entire Mono framework and libraries included.

Even after the linker, the 6K HelloWord App still remains at 2.9M (more than 480 times the size of the HelloWorld App).

Needless to say that with Xamarin we are using a "runtime-over-runtime" environment i.e. Mono-over-Dalvik (or Mono-over-ART if you want)

Simplifying this, what I want to know is:

Since every APK includes the Mono framework, the Mono framework is installed with every app or just with the first app we install?

and...

After uninstall Xamarin apps, the Mono runtime is uninstalled too? If not, how do we uninstall Mono runtime?

Than you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just misunderstood the purpose of Mono runtime bundled with each Xamarin Android App.
It's not included in your App package, then installed on the system.
It's included in the package, so every time you run your app, it actually runs the Mono runtime **included in your package**, which then **runs your App**.

At first it may seem a little stupid (since every of your apps will have it's own Mono runtime packaged with it), but this enables you to have different apps on your phone, that will run on different Mono runtimes, kind of like in Docker containers.

The only exception to it, is using your phone, or Android emulator for debugging. Then, to speed up the process, it will install special "shared packages", but they're used only for debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I understand how Xamarin works. However I think the approach they choose is a shoot on Xamarin's feet. The only advantage of Xamarin is write code once for multiplatform. Concerning with language specifics, C# is something like Java-clone. So I think is not worth the megabytes of Mono overhead.

Comment: I like the idea of each app having its own Mono runtime bundled. Do you have any more info on the shared packages for debug mode? Where are they located? Can I for instance remove them from my device to rule out some odd behaviour?